# C# Entity Framework Core 5.0.1 automatically adding foreign keys?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm having an issue with EF Core automatically adding foreign keys while I didn't ask for it.

So basically I'm using code first migrations in C# with SQL Server, some models and the basic context down below. But as you can see with my example models I'm adding a dependency from Event -> Item, one to many, what I want is many to many. What I think is happening is that EFCore is switching the foreign key dependencies around? I had linktables before like EventItems.

Am I required to use the linktables again or is there an other way to fix this?

*Event model*

```cs
namespace Models
{
    public class Event
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Item> Rewards { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Event SQL*

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events] (
    [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [StartDate]   DATETIME2 (7)  NOT NULL,
    [EndDate]     DATETIME2 (7)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Events] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

*Item model*

```cs
namespace Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Item SQL*

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items] (
    [Id]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [EventId] INT            NULL,
    [Path]    NVARCHAR (MAX) DEFAULT (N'') NOT NULL,
    [QuestId] INT            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Events_EventId] FOREIGN KEY ([EventId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Events] ([Id])
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Items_EventId]
    ON [dbo].[Items]([EventId] ASC);
```

Comment: I get it too. With many versions changing, it gets rlly cumbersome. Maybe [this](https://dev.to/ruben_j/many-to-many-relations-in-entity-framework-core-3-1-and-5-59ei) helps. So, in your DB you will have a linking table (will be generated by EF), but you don't have to define the joining table as a model. You just have to do a tweak in the `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: I haven't done much with 5 but it looks like they added support for many:many relationships without ["explicitly mapping the join table" (in RC1 at least).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew).

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils and Ergis, both answers require me to create a reference from object A to objectB, and from that a reference from objectB to objectA, won't this cause any problems? Since I am trying to stick to SOLID/DRY design.

Comment: What do you mean by that? This has nothing to do with those principles. It's just **database design**: many-to-many.

Comment: @Ergis I meant that creating these models will make an infinite reference inside there. I'm not talking about the database design but talking about creating a model inside C# that is referencing itself infinitely. So When I access objectB from objectA, I'll be having a reference inside objectB to objectA again.

Comment: Man. I repeat: this is database design. And we are talking about an ORM. That's how it works. Point. It will only provide you with what you explicitly type. If you do `Event.EventItems`, it will not enter that 'infinite loop' you are talking about. There is a concept called `Lazy loading`. Is this your first time working with an ORM/EF ?

Comment: @Ergis ah sorry I had no idea something like Lazy loading existed, this is indeed my first time working with an ORM/EF.